# Error using variadic macro Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have defined the following macro:

```
#define DSLog(x,...) [[DSLogger sharedInstance] Log:(x, __VA_ARGS__)]

@interface DSLogger : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (void)Log:(NSString *)messageToLog,...;
- (NSArray *)errorLogArray;
@end
```

However I get a lot of "Expected expression" errors when I use it:

```
DSLog(@"setting dhcp to %ld", (long)dhcp);
```

> Expression result unused & Implicit conversion of long to NSString is
>   disallowed with ARC

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the parentheses that wrap the `Log` parameter in the macro are causing confusion.

Try:

```
#define DSLog(x,...) [[DSLogger sharedInstance] Log:x, __VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: Yes of course!  The compiler is attempting to interpret the last argument as a string.  I believe `##` is important too.

Comment: I solved this by using a function instead of that macro. But I checked this solution and it works.